# cc.ScrolView undefined in cocos2d-js

Tags: cocos2d-js

I tried to use ScrollView, TableView from cocos2d-js extensions and I noticed that it can't be seen!

I also tried to create a class from that example but i need to use from native class!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to load extensions, you should add "extensions" in "module" section in project.json. For example:

{
    ...
    "module": ["cocos2d", "extensions"]
}