# Progress Timer Cocos JS v3

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm newbie in cocos-js.

I want to make a health bar in cocos JS and try this code. And i choose to use Progress Timer. But when i use this code, it just show the bar, no running action. What's wrong ?

```
var healthBar = cc.ProgressTimer.create(cc.Sprite.create("health_bar1.png"));
            healthBar.setType(cc.PROGRESS_TIMER_TYPE_BAR);
            healthBar.setBarChangeRate(cc.p(1,0));
            healthBar.setMidpoint(cc.p(0,0));
            this.addChild(healthBar, 1);
            healthBar.setPosition(cc.winSize.width/2, cc.winSize.height/2);
            var to1 = cc.progressTo(5, 100);
            healthBar.runAction(to1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me very well:

```
var healthBar = cc.ProgressTimer.create(cc.Sprite.create("health_bar1.png"));
        healthBar.setType(cc.ProgressTimer.TYPE_BAR);
        healthBar.setBarChangeRate(cc.p(1,0));
        healthBar.setMidpoint(cc.p(0,0));
        healthBar.setPosition(cc.winSize.width/2, cc.winSize.height/2);
        this.getParent().addChild(healthBar, 1);
        var to1 = cc.progressTo(5, 100);
        healthBar.runAction(to1);
```

Comment: are you using cocos v3? that code is not working for me. No running action. I try set the percentage to 0, 50, 100. And nothing different.

Comment: In project.json in module section do you load "cocos2d"?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032681/cc-scrolview-undefined-in-cocos2d-js

Comment: it solved now. I'm sorry, it should be cc.ProgressTimer.TYPE_BAR but when i see my code it is cc.PROGRESS_TIMER_TYPE_BAR